# CodeIgniter email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email using codeigniter. Is there anyway I can send a message in any email for example gmail, yahoo, or outlook.com? This is what i have so far:

```
public function sendmail()
{
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;


    $this->load->library('email',$config); // load email library
    $this->email->set_newline ("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('user@gmail.com', 'sender name');
    $this->email->to('test@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Your Subject');
    $this->email->message('ed wow sir');
    if ($this->email->send())
        echo "nasend na!";
    else
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

and it shows error :

> Exit status code: 1 Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check
>   settings. Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might
>   not be configured to send mail using this method.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check with your hosting provider for sending mails. You can check with  mail function for checking mails are triggered.

In Codeigniter instead of send mail try to use smtp protocol and use gmail account for testing.

Comment: Ive already try smtp protocol and gmail it works on local host but what if i want to send it to yahoo or outlook, , and also up it on my server but it didnt work :(

Comment: what i am saying is use your any gmail account as smtp credential and try to send the email to yahoo or outlook check whether it is working or not

Comment: @karthi Instead of creating multiple answers why don't you re edit one by clicking on edit button below your answer.

Comment: thanks its working , , but what if i want to up it in my server is there anyway not to use gmail account as smtp credentials? what should i put in smtp user and password?

Comment: with default sendmail in server i have not tried for you i will try... and post

Comment: is it really compolsory to put smtp username and password??

Answer (score 0):

i am using this code:

sample code is:

```
$config = Array(
                  'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
                'smtp_host' => 'xxx',
                'smtp_port' => 587,
                'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
                'smtp_pass' => 'xx',
                 'smtp_timeout' => '5',
                 'smtp_auth' => true,
                  'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                'validate'        => TRUE,
                               'priority'       => 1,                      
                               'crlf'         => "\r\n",   
                              'newline' => "\r\n",
                                 'bcc_batch_mode' => FALSE,
                               'bcc_batch_size' => 200

            );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->from($from, $fromname);
        $this->email->to($to); $this->email->set_mailtype("html");


        $this->email->subject($subject);  
        $this->email->message($body);
        if (!$this->email->send())
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            else
        echo 'Your e-mail has been sent!';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using localhost you may need to set up your sendmail configuration there as well

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho) Sendmail Backend Setup for XAMPP & WAMP

When you need to send mail with google

```
$mail_config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '********',
    'smtp_pass' => '********',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->load->library('email', $mail_config);

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');


if ($this->email->send() == TRUE) {

   // Redirect to a success page or load a view or some thing
   redirect('success_page'); 

} else {
   echo $this->email->print_debugger();
   exit;
}
```

Codeigniter [Email Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Yahoo

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
```